# Как сделать чтобы каждый попап Fancybox начинался с соответствующего элемента?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Есть вот такой код с попапом Fancybox

```js
$('a#inlinetest').click(function() {

  $.fancybox.open($('.inlinedata').get(), {
    'type': 'inline',
    'overlayShow': true,
    'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
    'overlayColor': '#666',
    'overlayColor': '#666',
    'showNavArrows': true,
    'titleShow': false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="inlinetest" rel="group1" href="#inlinedata">Click here1</a>
<a id="inlinetest" rel="group1" href="#inlinedata">Click here2</a>
<a id="inlinetest" rel="group1" href="#inlinedata">Click here3</a>

<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="inlinedata" class="inlinedata">
    <div>HTML INLINE 1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="inlinedata" class="inlinedata">
    <div>HTML INLINE 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="inlinedata" class="inlinedata">
    <div>HTML INLINE 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/Poincare/vy91se0o/) на jsfibble

Как можно сделать чтобы при клике на ссылку 1 попапы начинались с 1-го, при клике на ссылку 2 - с второго попапа и тд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий способ:

**[Ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/meine/fnyLhbov/6/) на jsfiddle**

```js
$('a.inlinetest').on('click', (e) => {
  $.fancybox.open($('.inlinedata').eq($(e.target).index()).get(), {
    'type': 'inline',
    'overlayShow': true,
    'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
    'overlayColor': '#666',
    'overlayColor': '#666',
    'showNavArrows': true,
    'titleShow': false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="inlinetest" href="#inlinedata">Click here1</a>
<a class="inlinetest" href="#inlinedata">Click here2</a>
<a class="inlinetest" href="#inlinedata">Click here3</a>

<div style="display:none;">
  <div class="inlinedata">
    <div>HTML INLINE 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inlinedata">
    <div>HTML INLINE 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inlinedata">
    <div>HTML INLINE 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. `id` - должен быть **всегда** уникальным, на-то он и **"уникальный идентификатор"**

**UPD. После комментария**

```js
$("a.gallery").fancybox({
  "padding": 20,
  "imageScale": false,
  "zoomOpacity": false,
  "zoomSpeedIn": 1000,
  "zoomSpeedOut": 1000,
  "zoomSpeedChange": 1000,
  "frameWidth": 700,
  "frameHeight": 600,
  "overlayShow": true,
  "overlayOpacity": 0.8,
  "hideOnContentClick": false,
  "centerOnScroll": false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="gallery" rel="group" title="photo1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /></a>
<a class="gallery" rel="group" title="photo2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /></a>
<a class="gallery" rel="group" title="photo3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /></a>
```

**[Ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/meine/fnyLhbov/21/) на jsfiddle**

Comment: Но в этом случае попапы не листаются как в слайдере. Есть ли способ чтобы и функции слайдера остались?

Comment: @Poincare, в каком плане "не листаются как в слайдере"?

Comment: В изначальном варианте, с первого окна попапа можно перейти на на второй, третий и по кругу. Стрелка перехода на следующий попап (слайд) появляется при наведении.

Comment: @Poincare, обновил ответ. (листание стрелочками)

Comment: @Poincare, картинки вставил как пример, контент, соответственно, может быть разным. (Буквы, картинка, анимация и т.д. т.п....)

Comment: При переходе на следующий элемент бекгаунд затеняется. Каждый последующий попап открывается поверх предыдущего и при закрытии в какой-то момент попапа мы имеем черный фон

Comment: @Poincare, очень странно слышать такое, на моем устройстве все работает как должно. К сожалению, пока ничем не могу помочь, попробуйте "потыркаться" в коде, который я предложил, может достигнете Вашей цели. Спасибо за терпение.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Буду разбираться.